# EF Core does not create mapping tables of the database

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-core, ado.net

my input in the package manager console:

Scaffold-DbContext -Connection "Server=.;Database=MyDb;Integrated Security=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;" -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Data

after this command, all of my entities are created, except for one mapping table. Why it doesn't show up?

i wrote TrustServerCertificate=True, because without it the following error occured:

---

A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)

Comment: If you are using EF Core 6 with mapping tables they are not scsffolded by design

Comment: how can i make it scaffolded

Comment: Use EF Core Power Tools, it has an option to always scaffold them